# jw player : Can not load m3u8: Unable to fetch HTTP resource over HTTPS

Tags: jwplayer, wowza, jwplayer7

I got issue with my new jw player version , I have upgraded JWplayer 6.9 to JWplayer 7.6.1 (Premium)  version.

When I play video in chrome(v.52) without enabling flash I got following error

"Can not load m3u8: Unable to fetch HTTP resource over HTTPS"

My streaming engine is wowza , which runs over http (could not runs over https)

My application running over https (could not run over http)

Same configuration works in firefox (with flash + without flash) , it plays video.

Could you please guide us to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have hlshtml: true in the player setup config? You'll want to leave this as false (default) and also keep the default HTML5 player, which will fallback to Flash if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Chrome says cannot load http resource over https
```

Above statement is not related to wowza or media server. It is just it is insecure to load http contain over https.

It will work with flash in chrome and firefox because client get crossdomain.xml file which allow browser to get http (playlist and media segments ) over https(your web page).

It will work with/without flash in safari. 
For your problem, why do you want to disable flash in chrome because chrome does not natively support HLS. If you enable flash in chrome then your jwplayer will take HLS video and convert it to flash. Same goes for firefox.

Safari support HLS natively so it doesn't matter whether you have flash or not, your videos will be played.

Thanks

Comment: I have to give the support the the user's who don't have flash on their browser. This issue is only with the chrome browser. It was working properly before upgrading JWplayer from  V 6.9 to V 7.6.1.

Answer (score -1):

If your Wowza server has a public IP address, you can probably get a StreamLock certificate for free as part of your Wowza license. This will give you an additional domain name (e.g. https://0123456789abc.streamlock.net/) that has a working HTTPS certificate. Then you can use this domain name for your HLS stream.

More information:

https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?115-Media-security-overview

https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?454-How-to-get-SSL-certificates-from-the-StreamLock-service